# Using a GUID as a Primary Key

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, sql-server

I generally use auto increment IDs as Primary Keys in databases.  I am trying to learn the benefits of using GUIDs.  I have read this article: https://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/

I realise that these GUIDs are used to identify objects at the application level.  Are they also stored as the primary key at the database level.  For example, say I had the following class:

```
public class Person
{
public GUID ID;
public string Name;
..

//Person Methods follow
}
```

Say I wanted to create a new person in memory and then insert the Person into a database.  Can I just do this:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.ID=GUID.NewGUID();
PersonRepository.Insert(p1);
```

Say I had a database containing millions and millions of rows with a GUID as the Primary Key.  Will this always be unique? Am I even understanding GUIDs correctly?

I read this article earlier: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/15/cqs-with-database-generated-ids/.  It confuses me a little as it appears to recommend a happy medium between GUIDs and integers as Primary Keys.

**Edit 11/06/18**

I have come to believe that Guids are more suitable than ints for my requirements.  I am using CQRS more these days and GUIDs fit in more nicely.

I do notice that some developers model the GUIDs as strings in the domain model e.g. here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/BuyerAggregate/Buyer.cs - in this case: IdentityGuid is a GUID modelled as a string.  Is there any reason to do this other than what is stated here: [Use a custom value object or a Guid as an entity identifier in a distributed system?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239220/use-a-custom-value-object-or-a-guid-as-an-entity-identifier-in-a-distributed-sys).  Is it "normal" to model the GUID as a string or should I be modelling it as a GUID in the model and database?

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique

Comment: Not guaranteed to be unique, though it is unlikely you will ever see a collision. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid/1155027#1155027

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UUID vs Integer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/uuid-vs-integer)

Comment: see also: [UUID collisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/130261/31260)

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54690/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity-vs-material-code-which-is-the-best-choice-for-p/54741#54741, as well as lots of other questions - this topic has been asked, and answered, and argued about, often.

Comment: System I'm working with at the moment uses UUIDs. A nice property is that an ID uniquely identifies a record, as opposed to a sequential ID that identifies a record in that table.

Comment: @Justin, why do records need to be unique accross multiple tables?

Comment: @w0051977 they don't, but it can help - I've seen (admittedly badly coded) systems in which a `RoleId` was incorrectly used as a `UserRoleId` - and in dev environments it even worked, because ID `1` worked in both cases. With UUIDs the IDs would be different.

Comment: *I have come to believe that Guids are more suitable than ints for my requirements.* I say GUID is a last resort (and int for that matter). Indexing is pointless, and enigmatic, at best, in queries. OTOH, compound keys are DSL-ish in use, contextual, descriptive, flexible, and significant to performance. Queries on a sub-set of a compound PK can use it. I caution against creating PKs for its own sake - where none are warranted. Nothing wrong with indexing as needed on non-PK'ed tables. PKs intrinsically communicate data structure, relationships, and requirements.

Comment: @radarbob I think you are conflating the concepts of natural key, surrogate key an primary key. These are related but distinct ideas.

Answer (score 43):

GUIDs are by definition "Globally Unique IDentifiers".  There's a similar but slightly different concept in Java called UUIDs "Universally Unique IDentifiers".  The names are interchangeable for all practical use.

GUIDs are central to how Microsoft envisioned database clustering to work, and if you need to incorporate data from sometimes connected sources, they really help prevent data collisions.

Some Pro-GUID Facts:

- GUIDs prevent key collisions
- GUIDs help with merging data between networks, machines, etc.
- SQL Server has support for semi-sequential GUIDS to help minimize index fragmentation ([ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql), some caveats)

Some Ugliness with GUIDs

- They are big, 16 bytes each
- They are out of order, so you can't sort on ID and hope to get the insertion order like you can on auto-increment ids
- They are more cumbersome to work with, particularly on small data sets (like look up tables)
- The new GUID implementation is more robust on SQL Server than it is in the C# library (you can have sequential GUIDS from SQL Server, in C# it is random)

GUIDs will make your indexes bigger, so the disk space cost of indexing a column will be higher.  Random GUIDs will fragment your indexes.

If you know you aren't going to synchronize data from different networks, GUIDs can carry more overhead than they are worth.

If you have a need to ingest data from sometimes connected clients, they can be a lot more robust for preventing key collisions than relying on setting sequence ranges for those clients.

Comment: +1 and I would recommend reading the fine print on how the DB handles these.  We did this in Oracle and it went very poorly.  The queries had to be tweaked in an obscure way in order to hit the index.  The other thing that is problematic (IIRC) is that GUIDs generated on the same machine around the same time tend to be the same at the beginning and end but different in the middle so you need a special indexing strategy to handle this situation especially given the very large potential range.

Comment: @JimmyJames, Since the tag was for SQL Server, I tailored the answer for that.  Oracle was never really built around GUIDs or UUIDs, so I am not surprised with your experience.

Comment: Yep, I'm just suggesting that it's a good idea to understand really well what tradeoffs might be involved with this.  You mentioned a few, I wouldn't know if that is comprehensive.  In our case we were using the 'native' row ids as the PK.  So while I agree that Oracle doesn't handle this well, it is actually 'built' around this.  It's 128 bit so at the very least, in 2017, you are forcing the DB to use more than one register per key.

Comment: My understanding is that GUIDs are synonymous with UUIDs.  UUID is the standard name.  GUID is what Microsoft coined them prior to [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122).

Comment: I too am interested in what difference there is between GUIDs and UUIDs.   [Answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid) suggest the should be treated synonymously, but Stack Exchange is a far from definitive source */ducks*

Comment: GUID and UUID have become synonymous.Trying to treat them differently is just going to confuse people further down the road.

Comment: "They are out of order, so you can't sort on ID and hope to get the insertion order like you can on auto-increment ids"  Frankly, I'm not comfortable relying on that with regular ids either.  While it's possible in an extreme edge case for a lower id to get committed to disk later, I'd rather rely on useful sorting data, like an insertion timestamp.  Ids should be treated like memory addresses - everything has one, but the value itself is meaningless.  Use them for tiebreakers at most.  Especially since if you've got a bulk load, insertion order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @CortAmmon According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122), they are synonymous.  P. Leach of Microsoft was one of the creators of the RFC.  I think since the RFC was created, the two are the same.  From the RFC:  "UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique IDentifier)."  I think it's also useful to note that GUIDs were not created by MS.  They just created a new name for a technology adopted from elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think the point is that the internal ID of the row in the DB is a GUID.  It's the same for Oracle but I'm not sure that it's the case that the DB necessarily uses it in every lookup.

Comment: @MartinSmith This is outside of my expertise but there's something on the [UUID wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#As_database_keys) page that seems relevant.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's helpful info but I'm not a fan of this, as noted in various comments here.

Comment: Here's some information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate/  I will admit some of my information regarding GUIDs and SQL Server clustering is old.  Some things change and some things stay the same (for example SQL Server only supports failover clustering for the past several years)

Comment: There's also this information which can help as well: https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/  (You can have sequential GUIDs in SQL Server that are sequential for each machine it is on)

Comment: "SQL Server has optimizations for dealing with GUIDs so it shouldn't affect query performance much."  -1  Not nearly optimized enough.  I'm working with a DB where all PKs are guids, and its one of the primary causes of poor performance.

Comment: "SQL Server has optimizations for dealing with GUIDs **so it shouldn't affect query performance much.**"  Not true. That statement assumes other data types aren't optimized. Database servers also have optimizations for dealing with simple int values, for example.  GUIDs/UUIDs are a lot slower than using a 4-byte int value. 16 bytes will never be as fast as 4 bytes - especially on a machine that handles at most 4 or 8 bytes natively.

Comment: [a GUID as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8610/10832)

Comment: @MaxVernon is that the reason that some suggest the heaps+GUIDs combination?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - I suppose that is one way to "get around" the table fragmentation problem.  Although that would just be trading one issue for another.  Heaps are no good unless you can frequently `TRUNCATE TABLE` them.

Comment: @MaxVernon Good link and that links to a page of the so-called 'queen of indexing':  ["But, a GUID that is not sequential – like one that has it’s values generated in the client (using .NET) OR generated by the newid() function (in SQL Server) can be a **horribly bad choice**"](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)

Comment: If Ms. Tripp says it's true, it absolutely *is* true.

Comment: I made this community WIKI, and removed the most controversial statements.  Have at it and make it the most correct answer.  I get the feeling I was on the right track but was missing it on a couple key points.

Comment: As did I.  Thank you for the feedback, I did learn a few things.

Comment: @MaxVernon "Isn't optimal" is a massive understatement.

Answer (score 28):

> Will this always be unique?

*Always?* no, not always; it's a finite sequence of bits.

> Say I had a database containing millions and millions of rows with a GUID as the Primary Key.

Millions and millions, you are probably safe.  A million millions, and the [likelihood of a collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) becomes significant.  There's good news, though: you've already run out of disk space by the time that happens.

> Can I just do this?

You can; it's not a wholly good idea.  Your domain model shouldn't normally be generating random numbers; they should be inputs to your model.

Beyond that, when you are dealing with an unreliable network, where you might get duplicate messages, a *deterministically* generated UUID will protect you from having duplicate entities.  But if you assign a new random number to each, then you have more work to do to identify the duplication.

See the description of name-based uuid in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.3)

> Is it "normal" to model the GUID as a string or should I be modelling it as a GUID in the model and database?

I don't think it matters very much.  For most of your domain model, it is an *identifier*; the only query you ask of it is whether or not it is the same as some other identifier.  Your domain model won't normally be looking at the in memory representation of an identifier.

If GUID is available as a "primitive type" in your domain agnostic setting, I would use it; it allows the supporting context to choose appropriate optimizations that may be available.

What you should recognize, however, is that the representation of the identifier, both in memory and in storage, is a decision you are making in your implementation, and therefore you should be taking steps to ensure that the foot print of code coupled to that decision is small -- see [Parnas 1972](http://cabibbo.dia.uniroma3.it/asw/altrui/parnas-1972.pdf).

Comment: +1 for "you've already run out of disk space by the time that happens."

Comment: I feel the concept of "*deterministically generated UUID*" is essential (see Data Vault 2)

Comment: Indeed, Being able to re-calculate a UUID/GUID based on other data is an immense help, especially so to detect duplicates.  I once built a message processing system that stored the messages and pushed them through a processing pipeline.  I created a hash of the message and used that as a primary key throughout the system.  just that, in and of itself, solved me a LOT of issues to identify the message when we had to scale out.

Comment: A million millions = 2^40. That makes 2^79 pairs of possible collisions. GUID has 2^128 bits, so the chance is one in 2^49. It's much much more likely that you have a bug that reuses the same GUID for two records, or that mistakenly believes there is a collision where there is none.

Comment: I am going back through my historic questions.  Before I accept; could you have a look at my edit?

Comment: Thanks.  Just so I am clear; the answer is suggesting a GUID in the domain model (C#) and a unique identifier (rather than say a varchar) in the database (SQL Server).  I notice that is different to what is here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/BuyerAggregate/Buyer.cs

Comment: Perhaps those developers needed to optimize their trade offs differently.

Comment: You will never exhaust the set of available GUIDs. The number of any objects in the known universe is less than its size.
Since the beginning of the universe caesium 133 underwent a hyperfine transition much less number of times than that.
So it is safe to assume the uniqueness of GUIDs.

Answer (score 12):

The GUID or [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) will very likely be [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid/1155027#1155027) because of how they are generated and they provide a safe way to guarantee uniqueness without having to communicate with a central authority.

Benefits of GUIDs as a Primary Key:

- You can copy data between different shards of a cluster and not need to worry about PK collisions.
- It allows you to know your primary key before you have inserted any records.
- Simplifies the transaction logic for inserting child records.
- Cannot be easily guessed.

In the example you provided:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.ID = GUID.NewGUID();
PersonRepository.Insert(p1);
```

Specifying the GUID before insertion time can save a round trip to the database when inserting successive child records and allow you to commit them in the same transaction.

```
Person p2 = new Person();
p2.ParentID = p1.ID
PersonRepository.Insert(p2);
```

Detriments to GUIDs as a Primary Key:

- They are large 16 bytes meaning they will consume more space as indexes and foreign keys are added.
- They do not sort well as they are essentially random numbers.
- Index usage is very, very, very bad.
- A lot of leaf moving.
- They are hard to remember.
- They are hard to verbalize.
- They can make URL's harder to read.

If your application has no need for sharding or clustering it would be best to stick with a smaller, simpler data types such as int or bigint.

Many databases have their own internal implementations that attempt to mitigate the storage problems caused by GUID's and SQL Server even has a function [newsequentialid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql) to help with the ordering of UUID's allowing better usage of indexes and they generally have better performance characteristics.

Additionally, from the perspective of a tester, user, or developer working with the application, using an ID over a GUID will significantly improve communication. Imagine having to read a GUID over a phone.

In the end, unless large scale clustering or obfuscating URLs is a requirement it's more pragmatic to stick with auto-incrementing IDs.

Comment: One thing to consider is that depending on the type of [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), they contain information that could potentially be used to identify the machine they are generated on.  The pure random variant may be more likely to collide without sufficient entropy.  This should be considered before use in a URI.

Comment: Agreed, though one should never expose their primary key in a URL. Some more appropriate method should be used to ensure that there is no secure data leaking to external system.s

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood.  I assumed "They can make URL's harder to read." implied that they would be used there.  I'm not sure I agree that in general using the key in the URI is necessarily always a problem but it could be, for sure.

Comment: There’s one more use case: heavy insert OLTP databases in which the locking for the sequence is a bottleneck. According to my Oracle DBA friend, this is not as rare as it sounds, you don’t even need large scale or clusters for that. • In the end, weigh down pros and cons (and don’t confuse pros/cons of UUIDs with pros/cons that are not specific to UUIDs as some posters do) and **measure**.

Comment: If you use newsequentialid then you have to go to the db to get the id (like with an identity int), don't you? What is the benefit here.

Comment: The main reason to use them is that having a GUID as your clustered index key will cause heavy fragmentation, where as the sequential GUID will not. This comes with some performance benefits as well as some security pitfalls, such as being predictable.

Comment: @mirabilos I'd be interested in understanding how/when that isn't solvable by increasing the size of the sequence block.

Comment: @mirabilos Also, I would not recommend using 128 bit keys in Oracle.  See my comment on Berin's answer.  The performance around these kinds of PKs in Oracle can be dreadful if you don't make special allowances for it.

Comment: You can "help" the fragmentation by generating a clientside "sequential-guid-like" value (in c# for example).   UuidCreateSequential generates sequential GUIDs like these:

19F287B4-8830-11D9-8BFC-000CF1ADC5B7
19F287B5-8830-11D9-8BFC-000CF1ADC5B7
19F287B6-8830-11D9-8BFC-000CF1ADC5B7
19F287B7-8830-11D9-8BFC-000CF1ADC5B7
19F287B8-8830-11D9-8BFC-000CF1ADC5B7 see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/rpcrt4.UuidCreateSequential

Comment: @mirabilos Fon contention, using some kind of thread-local Hi-Lo algorithm would be IMHO a simpler solution and you'd still get smaller and mostly sequential IDs.

Comment: @mirabilos To be clear, when I say dreadful we ended up having inserts that were taking **minutes** per row.  It started off OK but after there were 10's of thousands of rows, it went sideways really fast.  If it's not obvious, 10s of thousands of rows is a very small table.

Answer (score 6):

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.ID=GUID.NewGUID();
PersonRepository.Insert(p1);
```

This is by far the most important reason for using GUIDs.

The fact that you can create a unique id without your code knowing about or communicating with your persistence layer is a huge benefit.

You can be sure that the Person object you just generated on your server, pc phone, laptop, offline device or whatever is unique across all your servers all over the world however distributed.

You can stick it in any kind of database rdb or no-sql, file, send it to any webservice or throw it away immediately as uneeded

No you will never get a collision.

Yes inserts can be slightly slower as the index may need to be fiddled with.

Yes it is bigger than an int.

- edit. had to shoot off before finishing up.

I know many people feel strongly about auto inc ints and this is a controversial topic with DBAs

But I really cant state strongly enough how superior guids are. You should use guids by **default** in any application.

auto inc ints have many many flaws

- You use a No-Sql distributed db. You simply cant talk to all the other instances to find out what the next number is.
- You use a message queue system. Things need IDs before they hit the db
- You are creating several items and editing them before saving. Each needs an id before you have hit the db
- You want to delete and re-insert rows. Make sure you don't count up your auto inc ids and run out!
- You want not to expose how many Orders you have taken this year to every user
- You want to move anonymised data from production to test and keep the relationships intact. But not delete all the existing test data.
- You want to merge your single tenant product into a multi tenanted database but everyone has an order 56.
- You create objects which are persisted but ephemeral. (incomplete orders) again, dont use up all your ints with stuff that no longer exists.

The list is endless and they are all real problems which happen to people all the time. unlike running out of diskspace because of slightly larger FK cols

Finally the massive issue with ints is **you run out of them**!!! ok in theory you dont, there are loads. But in practice you do because people don't treat them like random numbers with no meaning. they do things like

- oh I don't want customers to think we are new. start at 10,000
- I had to import a load of data so I just upped the seed to 1m so we know what is imported
- we need category's of data. every period start at the next million so we can use the first digits as a magic number
- I deleted and reimported all the data again with new ids. Yes even the audit logs.
- use this number, which is a composite key, as the id of this other thing

Comment: There's nothing factually wrong with this answer, but I would (to ward off further downvotes) perhaps make explicit the caveat that even though real-life applications won't encounter collisions, it is theoretically possible. (Or perhaps 45+ exabyte databases are more prevalent than I thought...). Though I do think the language "the most important reason" is a bit strong, this is what I find most useful.

Comment: its more likely that an auto inc int will collide than a guid

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "collide." In the same table, the chance of an auto inc int colliding is zero.

Comment: thats just not true. you can easily get an int collision simply by inserting a higher value than the current seed or resetting the seed to a lower value

Comment: -1 for "You should use guids by default in any application."  It Depends™.  And as others have shown, GUIDs/UUIDs, are absolutely not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: "It depends" answers are useless, sure there are going to be some odd applications where an int is better. But chances are your application isnt one of them. GUIDs are the most unique thing you can get

Comment: I think there will be some odd applications where guids are better.  Unique isn't the most important thing to consider.  Your "flaws" of ints are massively overblown, and you don't consider any of the many downsides of guids.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say no, don't use GUIDs as primary keys.  I'm actually dealing with such a DB now, and they are one of the primary causes of performance issues.

The extra 12 bytes add up quickly; remember, most PKs will be FKs in other tables, and just three FKs in a table you now have 48 bytes extra for every row.  That adds up in the table and in indexes.  It also adds up in disk I/O.  Those extra 12 bytes need to be read and written.

And if you're not using sequential guids and the PKs are clustered (which is what happens by default), SQL will from time to time have to move entire pages of data around to squeeze more into the right "spot."  For a highly transaction database with lots of inserts, updates and deletes, things bog down fast.

If you need some kind of unique identifier for syncing or something, add a guid column.  Just don't make it the PK.

Answer (score 3):

**Always use database generated, auto-incrementing Primary Keys(PKs).**

Why use auto-incrementing instead of GUID/UUID?

- GUID(UUID)s do not prevent key collisions since they are not unique and there is no way to make them unique since they are generated from numerous sources.
- GUIDs do not help with merging as they greatly increase the already time-consuming merge process with extremely long, non-integer PK and FK columns that take a great deal of time to process. Remember that for most PKs, there will be at least 1 other table with at least 2 keys of the same size: it's own PK and a FK back to the first table. All have to be resolved in a merge.

But how then to handle shards, clusters, etc.?

- Create multi-column PKs made up of separate columns identifying each shard/cluster/database/whatever that manages it's own auto-incrementing keys. For example...

A 3-column PK for a clustered table might be...

```
 DB | SH | KEY     |
----|----|---------|
 01 | 01 | 1234567 |
```

But What About...?

- Multiple trips to the database -- Most applications have no need to uniquely identify a record being created until it's inserted into the database since that thread/session/whatever is only working on one at a time. If the application really does need this ability, use an application generated temporary PK *that is not sent to the database*. Let the database then put it's own auto-increment PK on the row when it's inserted. Inserts will use the temporary PK, while updates and deletes will use the permanent PK assigned by the database.
- Performance -- Computers can process simple integers far faster than anything else because of the greatly larger domain if possible values per element in a GUID(37) vs. an integer (10). Remember too that each character in a GUID must first be converted into a number to be manipulated by the CPU.

**Common Misuses of Primary Keys**
PKs have only one purpose... to absolutely uniquely identify a row in a table. Anything else is an all-too-common misuse.

Detecting Missing Records

- **Missing records cannot be detected by looking at the PKs.** Bless QA for at least attempting to ensure data quality. However, they and programmer's lack of understanding of how keys in modern database systems are assigned often leads them to the misbelief that a missing number in an auto-incrementing PK means missing data. It does ***not*** because...
- For performance, database systems allocate blocks of numbers in 'sequences'(batches, ranges) to minimize trips to the actual database in storage. The size of these sequences of numbers is often under the control of the DBA but may not be tunable on a per-table basis.
- The key takeaway is... unused numbers from these sequences are never returned to the database so there are always gaps in the PK numbers.
- Why would there be unused numbers you ask? Because a variety of database maintenance actions may cause sequences to be abandoned. These are things like restarts, bulk reloads of tables, some types of restoration from backups and some other operations.

Sorting

- Sorting by PK is very error-prone since most people will think it lists the rows in the order they were created and that that corresponds to clock time. Mostly, but not necessarilly.
- Database engines are optimized for maximum performance and that may mean delaying insert of the results of a long-running complicated transaction in order to insert short simple ones, "out-of-turn" so to speak.

Comment: What are your thoughts on table schema such that the only unique column is a database-created auto-incrementing primary key?  Particularly for tables that have no foreign key but whose primary key is the foreign key for several related tables?

Comment: I've added much more to the answer along those lines. Original answer was incomplete due to the Android SE app I'm on hanging. I think a major rewrite of the app is in development.

Comment: So in your view it would be okay for a table to contain any number of rows that were identical save for their auto-incrementing primary key?

Comment: @RibaldEddie - As far as what the DB is designed to allow... absolutely. Deletions are easy. When your scenario occurs, I would consider it a bug to be fixed in the software and then delete either row. The much more common case though is two records for the same thing with slightly different data so they must be merged. If a column is empty in one record and has a value in the other, the choice is obvious and can be automated. Often the datetimestamp can be used to arbitrate an automated merge. Some duplicates require a person to finish and verify the merge based on business rules.

Answer (score 2):

> I realise that these GUIDs are used to identify objects at the application level. Are they also stored as the primary key at the database level.

That's where you should stop, right there, and rethink.

Your database primary key should NEVER have business meaning.
It should be meaningless by definition.

So add the GUID as your business key, and a normal primary key (usually a long int) as the database primary key.
You can always put a unique index on the GUID to ensure uniqueness.

That's talking database theory of course, but it's good practice as well.
I've dealt with databases where the primary keys had business meaning (one customer had thought to save some database resources by using them as employee numbers, customer numbers, etc. etc. for example) and it always leads to trouble.

Comment: How is this any different than querying from the application layer using an integer primary key? At that point, it also is being used to identify objects at the application layer. You kind of need a way to identify objects in a database from the application layer.

Comment: @icirellik the primary key is meant for internal use by the database, to link parent and child records and the like. It's NOT meant for use by application logic, you use business IDs for that, like a product number or name.

Answer (score 2):

Like anything, there are advantages and disadvantages to doing this:

**The Good:**

1. Your keys are always the same length (very large databases can have very large keys)
2. Uniqueness is pretty much guaranteed - even when you're generating them from a separate system, and/or haven't read the last ID from the database

**The Bad:**

1. As mentioned a lot above - larger indexes and data store.
2. You can't order by ID, you have to order by something else.  More indexes, probably less efficient.
3. They're less human readable.  Integers are generally easier to parse, remember and type for people.  Using GUIDs as IDs in WHERE clauses across multiple joined tables can make your head melt.

Like everything, use them where appropriate, don't be dogmatic – in many situations auto-incrementing integers are better, occasionally GUIDs are great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use GUID as primary key.  The down side is size and rapid fragmentation of the index.

Unless you need uniqueness across databases (e.g. a cluster) integer is preferred.

Comment: GUID generators may produce the same GUID more than once, therein lies a flaw. Whether they will or not depends on their granularity, mainly on the interval between clock ticks. E.g. a clock based generator may only tick over every 100ms, leading to 2 GUIDs requested within that 100ms on that machine being identical. There are ways to avoid that, mostly, but many GUID generators work entirely off of IP address and/or MAC address and a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this issue - the solution is a halfway house between GUID and int values, taking the best of both.

The class generates a pseudo random (but increasing over time) Id value, which is similar to a [Comb GUID](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Id/GuidCombGenerator.cs).

The key advantage is that it allows Id values to be generated on the client, rather than using auto-increment values generated on the server (which requires a round trip) with almost zero risk of duplicated values.

The generated values only use 8 bytes rather than 16 for a GUID, and not dependent on one specific database sort order (e.g. [Sql Server for GUIDs](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx)). The values could be expanded to use the whole unsigned long range, but this would cause issues with any database or other data repository that only has signed integer types.

```
public static class LongIdGenerator
{
    // set the start date to an appropriate value for your implementation 
    // DO NOT change this once any application that uses this functionality is live, otherwise existing Id values will lose their implied date
    private static readonly DateTime PeriodStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    private static readonly DateTime PeriodEndDate = PeriodStartDate.AddYears(100);
    private static readonly long PeriodStartTicks = PeriodStartDate.Ticks;
    private static readonly long PeriodEndTicks = PeriodEndDate.Ticks;
    private static readonly long TotalPeriodTicks = PeriodEndTicks - PeriodStartTicks;

    // ensures that generated Ids are always positve
    private const long SEQUENCE_PART_PERMUTATIONS = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF; 

    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    private static readonly object Lock = new object();
    private static long _lastSequencePart;

    public static long GetNewId()
    {
        var sequencePart = GetSequenceValueForDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);

        // extra check, just in case we manage to call GetNewId() twice before enough ticks have passed to increment the sequence 
        lock (Lock)
        {
            if (sequencePart <= _lastSequencePart)
                sequencePart = _lastSequencePart + 1;

            _lastSequencePart = sequencePart;
        }

        // shift so that the sequence part fills the most significant 6 bytes of the result value
        sequencePart = (sequencePart << 16);

        // randomize the lowest 2 bytes of the result, just in case two different client PCs call GetNewId() at exactly the same time
        var randomPart = Random.Next() & 0xFFFF;

        return sequencePart + randomPart;
    }

    // used if you want to generate an Id value for a historic time point (within the start and end dates)
    // there are no checks, compared to calls to GetNewId(), but the chances of colliding values are still almost zero
    public static long GetIdForDateTime(DateTime dt)
    {
        if (dt < PeriodStartDate || dt > PeriodStartDate)
            throw new ArgumentException($"value must be in the range {PeriodStartDate:dd MMM yyyy} - {PeriodEndDate:dd MMM yyyy}");

        var sequencePart = GetSequenceValueForDateTime(dt.ToUniversalTime());
        var randomPart = Random.Next() & 0xFFFF;
        return ( sequencePart << 16 ) + randomPart;
    }

    // Get a 6 byte sequence value from the specified date time - startDate => 0 --> endDate => 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF
    // For a 100 year time period, 1 unit of the sequence corresponds to about 0.022 ms
    private static long GetSequenceValueForDateTime(DateTime dt)
    {
        var ticksFromStart = dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - PeriodStartTicks;
        var proportionOfPeriod = (decimal)ticksFromStart / TotalPeriodTicks;
        var result = proportionOfPeriod * SEQUENCE_PART_PERMUTATIONS;
        return (long)result;
    }

    public static DateTime GetDateTimeForId(long value)
    {
        // strip off the random part - the two lowest bytes
        var timePart = value >> 16;
        var proportionOfTotalPeriod = (decimal) timePart / SEQUENCE_PART_PERMUTATIONS;
        var ticks = (long)(proportionOfTotalPeriod * TotalPeriodTicks);
        var result = PeriodStartDate.AddTicks(ticks);
        return result;
    }
}
```